# Why do I have extra items in my inventory?

Tags: card-hunter

I notice when I'm in the shop, that in my inventory, I have many items that are above my level, that I never received as rewards. Where are they coming from? I have not seen them come out of a chest, and I do not have a premium account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have already gone through the multiplayer tutorial? The items used by your group of adventurers there appear in your inventory later on in campaign mode, as all your gear is shared between both adventurer teams.

I believe these are the items you are referring to.